# C# Form closing all threads join

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have this simple piece of code:

```
private volaile bool working;
private volatile List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
private volatile Form Face;

public void Start(int n) 
{
    working = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while(working) 
            {
                // do some work     
            }
        });
        threads.Add(worker);
        worker.Start();
    }
}

public void Stop() 
{
    if(working)
    {
        working = false;

        logger.Info("Waiting threads join");
        foreach (Thread worker in threads)
        {
            worker.Join();
        }
        logger.Info("Threads joined");
    }
}

private void Face_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Face.Invoke(new Action(() => {Stop();}));
    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Face form creates on programm start and have some controls, so when I use Start() and Stop() methods, everything works fine (all threads join normally).

But when I press "X" Form button, programm stacks on "Waiting threads join". Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Does the same happen if you delete the `Environment.Exit`? What does the call stack say?

Comment: Yes, without `Enviroment.Exit`, the same happens, because programm cannot reach that piece of code, it stacks after `logger.Info("Waiting threads join")`. Call stack says nothing, because programm honestly waits for all threads join.

Comment: The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx) state that "The caller will block indefinitely if the thread does not terminate", so I'd imagine that is probably the case here, I'd imagine this is down to the endless loops but I'm not completely sure

Comment: I don't see any code in stop that sets `working` to false. When does the worker determine that they have to stop? Maybe you should set `working` to `false` before you join the threads. Why do you need `Face.Invoke`? Who is calling `Face_Closing`? The sender should be `Face` and in this case its called out of the UI-thread and you don't need to invoke it. But this should not be your problem.

Comment: @Verarind Yes, I'm sorry, forgot about that code string, have a look at the code now (Stop() method), please.

Comment: What are the threads actually doing (in the //do some work part)? It may be due to a deadlock.

Comment: You should give all your threads a unique [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name(v=vs.110).aspx) (maybe `"Thread" + i`). Then run into the deadlock, check the current threadname to join. Freeze all other threads in the thread overview and debug only this thread to determine why it doesn't stop.

Comment: @Rob some non-blocking operations, moreover to test this code, I used `Console.Writeline("Thread " + n + " here!");` instead `// do some work`. So, no blocks by working code.

Comment: You should also use .IsBackground= True; on the threads before starting them

Comment: Waiting for threads to terminate upon form closure, or total process closure, is a well known deadlock-generator.  You should design your system so that you don't have to wait in GUI handlers for anything, at any time.  Waiting in event-handers is universally bad.

Comment: I embed your code in my app. It works.

Comment: @hungndv That's kind of strange situation...

Comment: @MartinJames Any design suggestions to avoid this situation in my question?

Comment: @MartinJames I'd be highly interested in seeing how to do it better.

Comment: @J.Leeroy Did you ever fixed the issue? I'm facing the same issue for a couple days already

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread sample = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread1));
        sample.IsBackground= true;
```

try to set the threads as background threads.